# Does this method call violate the Law Of Demeter?

Tags: law-of-demeter

Say you have something like the following (sadly, I'm not allowed to post the original code):

```
public void foo() {
    MyObject obj = getMyObject();

    bar(obj);
}

public void bar(MyObject obj) {
   Type type = new Type(obj.getOtherObject());
}
```

`foo` calls `bar`, passes in `obj`. But instead of using `obj`,it calls a getter on it to retrieve the needed information. Does this violate the Law Of Demeter?

Would it be better to write something like this:

```
public void foo() {
    MyObject obj = getMyObject();

    bar(obj.getOtherObject());
}

public void bar(MyOtherObject otherObj) {
   Type type = new Type(otherObj);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed according to the wiki on the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter):

> The fundamental notion is that a given object should assume as little
>   as possible about the structure or properties of anything else...

Your `bar` assumes that a given `MyObject` (a concrete type so strongly coupled, again against LoD) has a method called `getOtherObject`, so your proposed solution sorts the assumption and moves the code closer to adhering to LoD.  You can go even further and instead provide the type that `bar` wants:

`bar(new Type(obj.getOtherObject());`

Depending on your language, can you not pass an interface/contract instead of a solid type?  This would turn the strong coupling into a looser coupling.

Of course, if this is all internal to a given object then perhaps it isn't breaking LoD because it's a "close friend":

> - Each unit should have only limited knowledge about other units: only units "closely" related to the current unit.
> - Each unit should only talk to its friends; don't talk to strangers.
> - Only talk to your immediate friends.

In OO I think your original code is breaking LoD based on this argument:

> ...an object A can request a service (call a method) of an object
>   instance B, but object A cannot "reach through" object B to access yet
>   another object, C, to request its services. Doing so would mean that
>   object A implicitly requires greater knowledge of object B's internal
>   structure.

To me it seems that you are using `obj` in order to call `getOtherObj`.  Your proposed code is a potential solution.